# Can't import necessary provider of github library in my project (Angular 2)

Tags: angularjs, intellij-idea, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services

The library is [Dragule](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula) which its a specific wrapper for angular 2 so I can implement drag and drop abilities.

Im using a specific ver of Angular 2 which is `2.0.0-beta.15` so to be able to use it I had to add to my dependencies specific commit that will support this ver, this is what I added:

```
"ng2-dragula": "git://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula.git#0cdcd52b1a486609ed4b4a43465b1dac2bb1b007"
```

then after I did `npm install` I had to add to my dircative `Dragula` and to my providers `DragulaService` but I could not find the import for `DragulaService`, usually intellij is recognizing it and I do alt+enter to import it but now it didnt recognize it...does someone knows how can I get over it?

Comment: If you navigate to `node_modules` do you see that class there? Did you notice if IntelliJ finished indexing?

Comment: @acdcjunior yes it added two folders to node_modules, dragula and ng2-dragula